# Finding if excel sheet contains array using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet

I'm trying to find out if an excel sheet contains an array (in any cell in the fourth sheet). The variable is a user input as shown:

```
$j = Read-Host "Enter sensor serial number"
$Sens_name = @("$j")
```

And the act of it trying to find the input looks like this, where $EPRB2_loca is the location of the excel file including file extension:

```
#Checking in EPRB 2 file
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$EPRB2_loca")
$WorkSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(4)
$WorkSheet.Name 
$EPRB2_file = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find("$Sens_name")
if ($EPRB2_file.HasArray -eq $false)
{
    $EPRB2_file = $null
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out why it won't show as it containing the array when I know it does?

Comment: Does your answer below mean that you have this working? I have had some success using the `ImportExcel` module by Doug Finke.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong command.

If anyone comes across this, use `.Count` instead of `.HasArray`